# What is the space $H^2([0,1])$ inside $L^2([0,1])$?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I understand that for a complex domain $\Omega$, $H^2(\Omega)$ is the closure of the span of $1, z, z^2, \dots $ . However, I am unsure if this space is any different on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: look up sobolev spaces

Comment: Polynomials are dense in $C([0,1])$ by Weierstraß' theorem, hence they are dense in $L^2([0,1])$.